# What is CloudPageBlob.Properties.PageBlobSequenceNumber?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I cannot find any documentation on what this number represents.
I only found generic doc pages that doesn't describe what it is.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobproperties.pageblobsequencenumber.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudpageblob.setsequencenumberasync.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know,`PageBlobSequenceNumber` is used for retry requests, the following is the snipped from the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-page), more details please refer to [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-page).

> This kind of conflict can occur when the original request does not return a status code between 100-499, or 503 (Server Busy). If one of these status codes is returned, you can be certain as to whether the request has succeeded or failed. But if the service returns a status code outside this range, there's no way to know the status of the original request.
>
> To prevent  of conflict, you can use the page blob's sequence number to ensure that when you retry a request, the original request will not subsequently succeed. To do so, you should increment the sequence number before retrying the original request. You can then use the conditional sequence number headers to ensure that the request fails if its sequence number does not match the expected sequence number.